# Unexpected identifier in json string

Tags: jquery, json, string

I have some code like below and it is returning `unexpected identifier` error or `unexpected token illegal`. I'm trying to fetch all those images into my `div` with `ID=mygallery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mediaInfoJson = '{
        "imageHost":"http://qacdn1.dxstatic.com", 
        "profileImageUrls":["/profile/de72378555bf4d1696dbf7c2ab4adf46.png", "/profile/eab0240101424198b97838b22c0ab140.png", "/profile/6390d85e6a7d4062b5e999df98826519.png", "/profile/07418578e6704c8eb9f335e621961e38.png"], 
        "yelloPagesAdsImageUrls":["/previews/CLBY/DEFAULT_S1202090682_thumb.jpg", "/previews/CLBY/DEFAULT_S1203286138_thumb.jpg", "/previews/CLBY/DEFAULT_S1203431377_thumb.jpg"]
    }';
```

mediaInfoJson = JSON.parse(mediaInfoJson);

```
    var imgHost = mediaInfoJson.imageHost;
    var profileImgPath = mediaInfoJson.profileImageUrls;
    var yellowPagePath =  mediaInfoJson.yelloPagesAdsImageUrls;
    var profileImgHTML = '';
    var yellowPageHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < yellowPagePath.length; i++ ){       
        var yellowPageUrl = imgHost + yellowPagePath[i];
        yellowPageHTML += '<img src="' + imgUrl + '"/>'; // This is to prepare HTML for all yellow page images 
    }
    $("#mygallery").append(yellowPageHTML);
});
```

Comment: `mediaInfoJson` is a string, JS strings don't have `.imageHost` property.

Comment: remove the `'` at the beginning and end of `mediaInfoJson` value

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes around your object, which makes it a string.

Comment: string is to parse. mediaInfoJson = JSON.parse(mediaInfoJson);  sorry I missed this

Answer (score 0):

Object `mediaInfoJson` should be like

```
mediaInfoJson = {
        "imageHost":"http://qacdn1.dxstatic.com", 
        "profileImageUrls":["/profile/de72378555bf4d1696dbf7c2ab4adf46.png", "/profile/eab0240101424198b97838b22c0ab140.png", "/profile/6390d85e6a7d4062b5e999df98826519.png", "/profile/07418578e6704c8eb9f335e621961e38.png"], 
        "yelloPagesAdsImageUrls":["/previews/CLBY/DEFAULT_S1202090682_thumb.jpg", "/previews/CLBY/DEFAULT_S1203286138_thumb.jpg", "/previews/CLBY/DEFAULT_S1203431377_thumb.jpg"]
};
```

Remove single quotes.